# CodeIgniter sess_destroy() for current session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code in Session.php:

```
// Is the session current?
if (($session['last_activity'] + $this->sess_expiration) < $this->now)
{   
    $this->sess_destroy();
    return FALSE;
}
```

for each session CodeIgniter sets cookies expire date as `$this->sess_expiration + time();`

if i set `this->sess_expiration = 5`, and send get request after 6 seconds it will contain no cookie, because browser will destroy it due to exp date. So CI will just create new session record, what is the solution for deleting old ones?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cleanup the session table in database, which is used to store the session information. This table should be named `ci_sessions`.

Comment: you mean delete old records each time using 'last_activity'?

Comment: You can change session settings in configuration file. And set `$config['sess_expiration']` in `config.php`